# Office 2010 Product Key & Registration Lookup

Tags: python, registry, ms-office

I have a small python program I wrote for a friend, one of the tasks is to audit the Office Version & Product Key on the machine it's run on.

I was able to locate the 32bit/64bit keys in the registry easily but it seems my algorithm breaks down on the new Office 2010 system.

My first problem is there's now 30+ entries under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Registration`
Although only one seems to have a `DigitalProductID` However this entry has NO INFORMATION about the suite. (Just the individual products in it)

I need to pull the version of office installed, I.E. `Office 2010 Home & Student`, the only thing I can find in the key is `Office 2010`

Strangely enough the key entry that on previous versions of office that had the full name w/ edition now reports Professional when H&S is installed.

Also it seems the `DigitalProductID`'s decoding algorithm has changed. The same code that decodes the ID properly for 2000-2007 seems to yield a completely wrong code now.

I cannot find any information about office 2010, all results keep pointing me back to the old editions & the same information I used to make the previous version of this tool.

What I need to accomplish:

- Return the Office Version & Edition (i.e. `Office 2010 Home & Student`)
- Decode the ProductKey using the new 2010 method, even just info about the (new?) algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read another section out of DigitalProductID

In CSharp I used

for (int ilByte = 52; ilByte <= 66; ilByte++)

to read the necessary section to calculate the product key for O2K - O2K7.

With Office 2010 you need to use

for (int ilByte = 808; ilByte <= 822; ilByte++)

to read the bytes which make out the product key.

Regarding the Suite I also have no idea where to pull it from registry.
Maybe it's worth contacting WMI for that information.

Comment: Interestingly enough I already found the answer a while ago, but as you are correct, I'll give you the accept so others will know this is confirmed working! Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The position may be correct for Office 2010 , but the algorithm to decode the key must be different than 2007.

Today we entered 3 new CD-Keys in 3 new Laptops and the old 2007 working algorithm returned a wrong CD-Key.

Comment: The Base-Encoding algorithm is exactly the same. MacGyver was right, the position of the key was incorrect. I applied the same algo to the new position and got the correct key.